# Pyinstaller - SQLAlchemy with SQLServer

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have a command line script I'm trying to build to an .exe file using pyinstaller. I'm using SQLAlchemy to connect to a database.

```
import sys
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
username = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]
hostname = sys.argv[3]
engine = 'mssql+pytds'
port = sys.argv[4]
technical_name = sys.argv[5]
uri = f"{engine}://{username}:{quote_plus(password)}@{hostname}:{port}/{technical_name}"
pool = create_engine(uri)
```

I run

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

But when I try to execute the resulting main.exe in the dist/ folder, I get the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mssql.pytds

How can I include mssql.pytds for sqlalchemy? I have sqlalchemy-pytds and python-tds installed in my environment and in requirements.txt

Edit: The above code executes successfully executes when I simply run

`python main.py user pw 127.0.0.1 1433 dbname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out. I ended up added all imports to the python script explicitly. I worked my way through it one error message at a time, adding whatever it said was missing.

For posterity, the version of the import section that allowed me to build and run the program as an exe:

```
import sys
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy_pytds
import sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator
import sqlalchemy.engine.default
import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy_pytds.dialect
```

Guessing there is a a better way to do this, but sharing here and will use this since it works for me. Would still interested if there are any 'cleaner' solutions/best practices here, and happy to accept another answer.